# Symfony: Generate URL route not found but it exists

Tags: symfony-3.4, symfony-routing

Here's a problem I've got to face a lot and I think that many people are having the same problem:

I try to call an action in controller and then to redirect to the URL I came from.
Let me show you the code:

I've got a basic form whose parameters are like that:

```html
<form id="messageCreationForm" action="{{ path('createMessage') }}" method="POST">
```

Submitting call the following method:

```js
    /**
     * @Route("/createMessage", name="createMessage")
     * Request $request
     */
    final public function createMessageAction(Request $request)
    {
    //Some logic...
        return $this->generateUrl(
            '/agent/campagne',
            [
                'agent' => $agent,
                'entretiens' => $talentMatchJobs
            ]
        );
    }
```

Then, i got this error:

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/agent/campagne" as such
>   route does not exist.

However, the route exists:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKl3s.png)
(I'm not allowed to submit image here so, click on the link to see it..)

I've also tried routes :

> /campagne, campagneIndex, campagne...

The corresponding method that defines the route is this one (this route give me the url /agent/campagne:

```js
/**
 * @Route("/campagne", name="campagneIndex")
 * @return Response
 */
final public function campagneIndexAction()
{
//Some logic...
}
```

I would really appreciate some help.. Thank you
Regards,

Maxime

Answer (score 1):

the `generateUrl` method take a route name as first parameter. here you need to use "campaignIndex" to be able to generate the "/agent/campagne" url.

if this doesn't work you can try to clear your cache or launch the `debug:router` command to see if the route is correct